# Checking null condition before adding new column in spark job scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-xml

I have a below schema

```
root
 |-- DataPartition: long (nullable = true)
 |-- TimeStamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _action: string (nullable = true)
 |-- env:Data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- al:FundamentalAnalytic: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _analyticItemInstanceKey: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _financialPeriodEndDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _financialPeriodType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _isYearToDate: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _lineItemId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- al:AnalyticConceptCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- al:AnalyticConceptId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- al:AnalyticIsEstimated: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- al:AnalyticValue: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _currencyId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- al:AuditID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- al:FinancialPeriodTypeId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- al:FundamentalSeriesId: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _objectType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _objectTypeId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- al:InstrumentId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- al:IsAnnual: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- al:TaxonomyId: long (nullable = true)
```

Now this is a xml files which varies frequently .
I want to process only tax which contains **env:Data.sr:Source.***
For that I have written below code

```
val dfType = dfContentItem.
    select(getDataPartition($"DataPartition").
        as("DataPartition"), 
        $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), 
        $"env:Data.sr:Source.*", 
        getFFActionParent($"_action")
        .as("FFAction|!|")
    ).filter($"env:Data.sr:Source._organizationId".isNotNull)
dfType.show(false)
```

But this works only when `sr:Source` is found in schema else I get below exception

> Exception in thread "main" `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException`: No
>   such struct field sr:Source in _type, cr:TRFCoraxData,
>   `fun:Fundamental, md:Identifier, md:Relationship`;

To ignore that I have null checkfor `sr:Source` ,but that is not working for me .
For that check also I am getting same error .

**Basically what i need is that is env:Data.sr:Source.* is null then i want to exit processing and next tag processing will start again .**

Comment: how are you doing your null check? post more code please

Comment: @StevenBlack something like this ...`val check=dfContentItem.select($"env:Data.sr:Source.*.isNotNull")`

Comment: What version of `spark`? and is the schema for a `DataFrame`?

Comment: @StevenBlack SPARK VERSION IS 2.2.0 and Yes it is of Data frame that i have created from xml file

Answer (score 0):

The [`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException) is usually thrown when something's wrong in the query - so I'm pretty sure it's because you're trying to filter a `null` on those occasions

Error handling in `scala` is typically done with an `Option` there's a [good article on it](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/dealing-with-null-in-spark-cfdbb12f231e) 
Try

```
def handleNulls(organizationId: String): Option[Boolean] = {
     val orgId = Option(organizationId).getOrElse(return None)
     Some()
}
val betterNullsUdf = udf[Option[Boolean], Integer](handleNulls)

val dfType = dfContentItem.
    select(getDataPartition($"DataPartition").
        as("DataPartition"), 
        $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), 
        betterNullsUdf($"env:Data.sr:Source.*"), 
        getFFActionParent($"_action")
        .as("FFAction|!|")
    ).filter($"env:Data.sr:Source._organizationId".isNotNull)
dfType.show(false)
```

Comment: I am getting `not enough arguments for method apply: (x: A)Some[A] in object Some. Unspecified value parameter x.` at some ..Also i have env:Data.sr:Source.* as array type

Comment: Also Steven in my case of env:Data.sr:Source.* is null then i want to exit processing the job for that tag .I dont think this can handle that